# powershell move-item argument with spaces

Tags: powershell, filepath, spaces

I have looked all about the web about `powershell` and path names with spaces, but nothing seems to work with this `cmdlet`.

My first argument doesn't have any spaces, but my second argument does:

```
Move-Item C:\Users\RB398970\Documents\WeekendUpdateReport\weekendCloseReport.pdf C:\Users\RB398970\Workspaces\Supply Chain\Document Templates\
```

I have tried surrounding the second argument with double quotes, with two sets of double quotes, with double quotes and nested single quotes, double quotes with single quotes in front of white spaces, using the ampersand in front, and multiple other things. None have worked.

I do know that the second argument is a valid path name - I can search it in my explorer and find the directory.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: As in copy and paste the error into your question please. Not a summary.

Comment: I just tried it with both arguments surrounded in " and it worked for me to move the file. So something like: Move-Item "C:\Users\RB398970\Documents\WeekendUpdateReport\weekendCloseReport.pdf" "C:\Users\RB398970\Workspaces\Supply Chain\Document Templates\"

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to the PowerShell ISE (integrated script editor)?  What is helpful with it is that you can do script checking to insure that you have the quotes in the right locations, etc.

Either of these should work for you..

```
Move-Item 'C:\Users\RB398970\Documents\WeekendUpdateReport\weekendCloseReport.pdf' 'C:\Users\RB398970\Workspaces\Supply Chain\Document Templates\'


Move-Item "C:\Users\RB398970\Documents\WeekendUpdateReport\weekendCloseReport.pdf" "C:\Users\RB398970\Workspaces\Supply Chain\Document Templates\"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the root issue. My problem was not that my file path contained spaces, but that my file path is one that my Windows Explorer shows as existing, yet does not actually have a local copy of. When searching for the second argument path in a DOS cmd window, it would not recognize it. That path is created by Sharepoint Workspace. I am not very familiar with the software, but my guess is that when it syncs with Shareoint, it does not store local files but contains references to where they are stored online. In any case, the lesson learned here is that if you are trying to use Sharepoint Workspace to update Sharepoint, it is complicated since it does not allow you to move files from a local machine to the software's workspace